# VMWare ESXi - Unable to expand datastore - error: An error occurred during host configuration

Tags: vmware, esxi

I am using ESXi 6.7U3
I am unable to expand an existing datastore with a new extent.
The error I get is:

```
Failed to extend VMFS datastore ds1_Media - An error occurred during host configuration.
```

If I dig into the ESXi VMKernal.log file, I see the below error:

```
2023-12-11T09:40:27.974Z cpu0:2099651 opID=7bb1f90b)LVM: 10418: Initialized naa.5000cca2aad1abdd:1, devID 6576d90b-4f918b88-600d-d0946604374b
2023-12-11T09:40:28.033Z cpu0:2099651 opID=7bb1f90b)LVM: 13543: Deleting device <naa.5000cca2aad1abdd:1>dev OpenCount: 0, postRescan: False
2023-12-11T09:40:28.098Z cpu0:2099651 opID=7bb1f90b)LVM: 11308: Device naa.5000039ae8d3e9a1:1 detected to be a snapshot:
2023-12-11T09:40:28.098Z cpu0:2099651 opID=7bb1f90b)LVM: 11315:   queried disk ID: <type 2, len 14, lun 0, devType 0, scsi 0, h(id) 848052112411752293>
2023-12-11T09:40:28.098Z cpu0:2099651 opID=7bb1f90b)LVM: 11322:   on-disk disk ID: <type 1, len 26, lun 0, devType 0, scsi 0, h(id) 11555196997763893705>
2023-12-11T09:40:28.098Z cpu0:2099651 opID=7bb1f90b)Vol3: 1108: Unable to register file system ds1_Media for APD timeout notifications: Already exists
2023-12-11T09:40:28.098Z cpu0:2099651 opID=7bb1f90b)LVM: 10708: Error adding space (0) on device naa.5000cca2aad1abdd:1 to volume 611e3285-36df454c-2b77-00133b21f43c: Not found
```

However, if I run the command

```
esxcli storage vmfs snapshot list
```

Nothing returns, indicating no LUN snapshots exist.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend to scan your disk sectors sometimes the MBR partition is failing or some sectors are.

Comment: Will take a look, run a scan on the disk